# Vertical centred alignment of text in table cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I would like to know how to put vertical centered text inside a table cell.

The problem with m column type is that i'm actually using [tabularx](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tabularx) to auto detect the width of the columns

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYY}
   & Lorem ipsum \newline Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing & Lorem ipsum \newline Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing \\
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing & A & B \\
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing & C & D \\
\end{tabularx}
```

I would like to vertical centering in the boxes the A, B, C, D text

Comment: Providing an example of what you have done or image of what you are looking for helps everyone understand your question a bit better.

Answer (score 7):

The `tabularx` documentation gives an explicit example of using an `m` column with small text

```
 \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
```

Your column definition already adds `\small` so you just need to make X use m instead of p so

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `tabularx`, you could use the features provided by the [tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\everyrow{\rowfont{\small}}
\noindent\begin{tabu} to\linewidth{X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]}
   & Lorem ipsum\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing & Lorem ipsum \par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing \\
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing & A & B \\
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing & C & D \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]